# How to combine many comparable find query in javascript

Tags: javascript, find

I made this script in javascript, it's work:

```
if(datatermid==16){
$('#Xhaut').find('[data-parent=16]').removeClass('active')
}
if(datatermid==17){
$('#Xhaut').find('[data-parent=17]').removeClass('active')
}
if(datatermid==18){
$('#Xhaut').find('[data-parent=18]').removeClass('active')
}
```

I thinks it's possible to combine all this lines into one , maybe somethink like :

```
$('#Xhaut').find('[data-parent=datatermid]').removeClass('active')
```

But it dont work...

can you please give me a solution?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the variable using the `+` operator to build your selector :

```
$('#Xhaut').find('[data-parent='+datatermid+']').removeClass('active')
```

You may also do the search in one step :

```
$('#Xhaut [data-parent='+datatermid+']').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: LOL doing it as a CW.

Comment: Would the find method be quicker?

Comment: @RGraham Probably, yes. But that's not worth the increased complexity

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well... I'd like a bigger part of my rep to come from harder ones...